# Nested elements in iOS: parent's background visible around the edges

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

I have nested elements where the parent's background is visible on iDevices. It creates something of a border/outline regardless of the browser (tried Chrome and Safari) similar to a [bleed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_%28printing%29) in printing.

Can anyone help me?

Here is a simplified code and JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5eTDD/6/

```
<div class="a">
   <div class="b"></div>
</div>​

.a {background:#000; margin:10px; display:inline-block}
.b {width:100px; height:100px; background:#fff;}​
```

**SCREENSHOT**:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the border is appearing on the anchor, not the list element. Try adding:

```
a {border:0 !important}
```

iDevices have an in-built stylesheet that sometimes causes this sort of stuff, which is why the !important is there - to override it. It might even be associate with your class of "active" - you could also try changing the class to something else, just try active1, and see if that fixes it, too.

Comment: The problem as far as I could narrow down is with the background which comes through around the border and between border and element. I simplified the example: http://jsfiddle.net/paHVg/6/ and above.

Comment: when you load that fiddle on your iPad, is it still doing the thing with the 'border'? - it's not showing any border for me on my iPhone. is it part of the background image you're using?

Comment: yes, it definitively does. the lines change color with the background.

Comment: actuall, nevermind, i zoomed right in and can now see the artifact you're talking about. i've never seen that before... as you say, looks like there is a bit of background around the border pixels. can you use margin instead of border for the same effect?

Comment: margin doesn't do the trick either. I updated the question because I noticed it happens even on a very basic nesting of divs.

Comment: you might have to put the margin (or border) on the outer element, not the element with the background on it - might need some (more) nesting. looks like it's a "bug" or weakness with the display on iDevices, not sure if there's going to be a "fix" as such.